# Michel Thiébaud's thesis ("Self-Dual Structure-Semantics and Algebraic Categories")

Tags: ct.category-theory, paper-request, profunctors, algebraic-theory

I am looking for a copy of Michel Thiébaud's 1971 thesis *Self-Dual Structure-Semantics and Algebraic Categories*, which appears to be an early reference for the relationship between the Kleisli construction and profunctors, among other things. However, only PhD theses after 1972 appear to be [publicly digitally available](https://libraries.dal.ca/find/theses.html) from Dalhousie University. Is a scan or other digital copy available anywhere?